# Inputs with different Display

Tags: c#

I want to display different outputs, but my program displays the same.
I hope you will help me!

Main:

```
        //DECLARATION
        Cake cake = new Cake();
        //INTEGERS
        int max = 5;
        int[] qty = new int[max];
        int[] price = new int[max];
        int i;
        int qty_search;
        int counter = 0, found = 0;
        //STRINGS
        string search;
        string[] cakename = new string[max];
        string[] id = new string[max];
        //CHAR'S
        char opt;
        //LOOP
        //MENU
        do
        {
            Console.Write("1 - add cake\n2 - display cake\n3 - search cake\n4 - increase qty\n5 - decrease qty\n6 - Update qty\nx - exit\nopt --> ");
            opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            //SWITCH CASES
            switch (opt)
            {
                //ADD CAKE
                case '1':
                    Console.Write("name: ");
                    cakename[counter] = Console.ReadLine();
                    cake.cake_Name = cakename[counter];
                    Console.Write("id: ");
                    id[counter] = Console.ReadLine();
                    cake.id = id[counter];
                    Console.Write("qty: ");
                    qty[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    cake.qty = qty[counter];
                    Console.Write("price: ");
                    price[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    cake.price = price[counter]; 
                    counter++;
                    break;
                //DISPLAY CAKE
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                    Console.WriteLine("id -.- Name -.- qty -.- price");
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", cake.id, cake.cake_Name, cake.qty, cake.price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    break;
                //SEARCH CAKE
                case '3':
                    found = 0;
                    Console.Write("enter your search cake id: ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (string.Equals(id[i], search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            found++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write("found = ");
                    Console.WriteLine(found);
                    break;

                case '4':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                     for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cake.id, cake.cake_Name, cake.qty, cake.price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Selected Item ID: ");
                    qty_search = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (qty_search == qty[i])
                        {
                            qty[i]++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("cake qty + 1");
                    break;

                case '5':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                     for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cake.id, cake.cake_Name, cake.qty, cake.price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Selected Item ID: ");
                    qty_search = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (qty_search == qty[i])
                        {
                            qty[i]--;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("cake qty + 1");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Console.WriteLine("-- update cake name --");
                    Console.WriteLine("Cake list");
                     for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cake.id, cake.cake_Name, cake.qty, cake.price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Select item ID: ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (search == id[i])
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                            cakename[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("cake updated");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                    Console.WriteLine("exit");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                    break;
            }
            //SWITCH CASE END
        } while (opt != 'x' && opt != 'X');
        //OUTER MENU LOOP END
        //PROGRAM TERMINATE
    }


}
```

}

Inputs:

First Input: 
     name:cake
     id: 2
     qty: 2
     price: 2

Second Input:
     name: cake2
     id: 3
     qty: 3
     price: 3

When I display:
    3 cake2 3 3
    3 cake2 3 3

It is the same, please help me.

Comment: please post the whole source code, or atleast parts of which take the input. For example, your `case '1'` and `case '2'` statements do not tell us what its `switch`ing over

Comment: we need other codes to answer the question

Comment: This is all my codes

Answer (score 1):

You do not create new `Cake` instances in your program. What you do is use same `Cake` instance and update it.

My Advice - Make an array of `Cake` and fill it in your loop

```
 Cake[] CakeArray = new Cake[MAX];
```

And you can access each object using

```
       CakeArray[0] = new Cake(); 
       CakeArray[0].ID =  Console.ReadLine();;
       CakeArray[0].Price =  Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

hope I helped you

Edit: Inside your Cases you can use Cake array as following

```
       case '2':
                Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                Console.WriteLine("id -.- Name -.- qty -.- price");
                for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                {
                   if(CakeArray[i]!=null){ // A safe check for null
                       Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", CakeArray[i].id, CakeArray[i].cake_Name, CakeArray[i].qty, CakeArray[i].price);

                    }
                 }
                 Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                 break;
```

Edit - Added a suggestion answer for first two cases - Follow this and update your full answer

```
 //DECLARATION

        //INTEGERS
        int max = 5;
        int i;
        int qty_search;
        int counter = 0, found = 0;
        char opt;

        Cake[] CakeArray = new Cake[max]; 
        do
        {
            Console.Write("1 - add cake\n2 - display cake\n3 - search cake\n4 - increase qty\n5 - decrease qty\n6 - Update qty\nx - exit\nopt --> ");
            opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            //SWITCH CASES
            switch (opt)
            {
                //ADD CAKE
                case '1':
                    CakeArray[counter] = new Cake();

                    Console.Write("name: ");
                    CakeArray[counter].cake_Name= Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("id: ");
                    CakeArray[counter].id = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("qty: ");
                    CakeArray[counter].qty= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("price: ");
                    CakeArray[counter].price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    counter++;
                    break;
                //DISPLAY CAKE
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                    Console.WriteLine("id -.- Name -.- qty -.- price");
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if(CakeArray[i]!=null){ // A safe check for null
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", CakeArray[i].id, CakeArray[i].cake_Name, CakeArray[i].qty, CakeArray[i].price);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    break;    
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                    break;
            }
            //SWITCH CASE END
        } while (opt != 'x' && opt != 'X');
        //OUTER MENU LOOP END
        //PROGRAM TERMINATE
    }
```

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. Make an array of `Cake` If you would want to fix the existing code then you would have to use `Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", i, cake_Name[i], qty[i], price[i]);` in the for-loop when printing

Comment: yes a good suggestion :0

Comment: KCdod can you give me the full code, plss!!!

Comment: you can update your code with my guidance :) It won't be that hard and you will learn a lot..

Comment: use newly added guide :) Hope you would manage the rest

Comment: @KCdod Thank you very much bro, you bring me more appreciation in my useless life

Answer (score 1):

When displaying cakes, you just output the values from the last one you entered as many times as there are cakes entered.

A quick fix would be to read the values from `string` and `int` arrays instead from the only `Cake` instance you have:

```
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", id[i], cakename[i], qty[i], price[i]);
}
```

It would be a beter idea to rewrite your program using an array of cakes `Cake[]` as KCdod suggests.

Comment: My prof. don't want me to use that kind of code but, Cake[] would be better but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

this is correct code you must write:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //INTEGERS
        int max = 5;
        Cake[] cakes = new Cake[max];
        int[] qty = new int[max];
        int[] price = new int[max];
        int i;
        int qty_search;
        int counter = 0, found = 0;
        //STRINGS
        string search;
        string[] cakename = new string[max];
        string[] id = new string[max];
        //CHAR'S
        char opt;
        //LOOP
        //MENU
        do
        {
            Console.Write("1 - add cake\n2 - display cake\n3 - search cake\n4 - increase qty\n5 - decrease qty\n6 - Update qty\nx - exit\nopt --> ");
            opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            //SWITCH CASES
            switch (opt)
            {
                //ADD CAKE
                case '1':
                    Console.Write("name: ");
                    cakename[counter] = Console.ReadLine();
                    cakes[counter] = new Cake();
                    cakes[counter].cake_Name = cakename[counter];
                    Console.Write("id: ");
                    id[counter] = Console.ReadLine();
                    cakes[counter].id = id[counter];
                    Console.Write("qty: ");
                    qty[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    cakes[counter].qty = qty[counter];
                    Console.Write("price: ");
                    price[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    cakes[counter].price = price[counter];
                    counter++;
                    break;
                //DISPLAY CAKE
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                    Console.WriteLine("id -.- Name -.- qty -.- price");
                    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} {3}", cakes[i].id, cakes[i].cake_Name, cakes[i].qty, cakes[i].price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    break;
                //SEARCH CAKE
                case '3':
                    found = 0;
                    Console.Write("enter your search cake id: ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (string.Equals(id[i], search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            found++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write("found = ");
                    Console.WriteLine(found);
                    break;

                case '4':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cakes[i].id, cakes[i].cake_Name, cakes[i].qty, cakes[i].price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Selected Item ID: ");
                    qty_search = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (qty_search == qty[i])
                        {
                            qty[i]++;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("cake qty + 1");
                    break;

                case '5':
                    Console.WriteLine("List of Cakes");
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cakes[i].id, cakes[i].cake_Name, cakes[i].qty, cakes[i].price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Selected Item ID: ");
                    qty_search = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (qty_search == qty[i])
                        {
                            qty[i]--;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("cake qty + 1");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    Console.WriteLine("-- update cake name --");
                    Console.WriteLine("Cake list");
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  {2}  {3}", cakes[i].id, cakes[i].cake_Name, cakes[i].qty, cakes[i].price);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    Console.Write("Select item ID: ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    {
                        if (search == id[i])
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
                            cakename[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("cake updated");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                    Console.WriteLine("exit");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                    break;
            }
            //SWITCH CASE END
        } while (opt != 'x' && opt != 'X');
        //OUTER MENU LOOP END
        //PROGRAM TERMINATE

    }
```